# How do I refer to a certain parameter of my Object that is queued up in my list?

Tags: java

How do I refer to a certain parameter of my Object that is queued up in my list?
We're currently working with lists and Im trying to compare a parameter with a specific parameter of an Object that is in my list. The class list only offers `getContent()`, but I don't need the object I need the parameter inside the object.

```
if (answer.equals(a)) {
    vocList.getContent(Vocabulary.getGerman());
}
```

I've got a getter in the class Vocabulary. Vocabulary is queued in my List

Vocabulary class:

```
public class Vocabulary {

    private String deutsch;
    private String englisch;

    public Vocabulary(String pGerman, String pEnglish)
    {
        english = pEnglish;
        german = pGerman;
    }

    public String getGerman()
    {
        return german;
    }

    public String getEnglish()
    {
        return english;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide the code here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post your code so that we can help you. A [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is strongly encouraged. Also see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You will need to, at least, post the `Vocabulary` class.

Comment: Are you looking up the object into the list base on certain properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of an object you need the getter you created in the Vocable class:

```
vocList.get(i).getGerman(); //i is the index of the object in your list.
```

So your Vocable class should look like this to actually store the values you create the objects with:

```
public class Vocable{

    private String german;
    private String english;

    public Vocable(String pGerman, String pEnglish){
        english = pEnglish;
        german = pGerman;
    }

    public String getGerman(){
        return german;
    }

    public String getEnglish(){
        return english;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The thing I was searching for was vocList.getContent().getGerman();

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a homework question since you say, "*We* are currently working with lists." So, I'll try to steer you in the right direction without giving the answers away. I also recommend you read [the Oracle Java Tutorial on Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html).

Now, to your question: You *want* to get a handle to the specific Object---once you have a handle for the Object, you can call its instance methods or access its fields' values. For example, suppose I have a `Rectangle` object:

```
public class Rectangle {

    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int width;
    public int height;

    public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

}
```

You can use the following code to print create a new `Rectangle` and then print its fields' values. Notice you have to get the element from the list (using `get(0)`) before I could access the `Rectangle`'s variables. You have to do the same thing in your code, but it looks like you're using a custom `List` implementation; So, you'll have to use the `getContent` method to get a reference to the object.

```
public class CreateObjectDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create an ArrayList
        static List<Rectangle> rectangleList = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

        //create a rectangle and add it to the array list
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50,50,100,75);
        rectangleList.add(rect);

        printFirstRectangle(rectangleList);

    }

    /** Prints the first rectangle in the list */
    private static void printFirstRectangle(List<Rectangle> rectangles){

        if (rectangles.size() > 0){ //if the list has at least one element

            //get the handle for the first element---the one at the 0th index
            Rectangle firstRect = rectangle.get(0);

            //print the result
            System.out.printf("First Rectangle, x=%d, y=%d, width=%d, height=%d\n", 
                                firstRect.x, 
                                firstRect.y, 
                                firstRect.width, 
                                firstRect.height);
        } else { //if the list is empty
            System.out.println("The list is empty.");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I appreciate ur effort, but my problem was much more simple than your answer. Still thank you for taking the time to help ppl out :)